# which column should I index

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

I have a table with 3 columns:

- `int UserID`
- `datetime WorkDate`
- `string WorkDetail`

Each user will have one `WorkDetail` per `WorkDate`. I'm using L2S and my where clause matches the `UserID` and the `WorkDate` like this:

```
where t.UserID == TheUserID && t.WorkDate.Date == TheDate.Date
```

Should I keep the order of the where parameter as is? Should I index the date or the `userID`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each users should have only one WorkDate then make that the primary key in the database. It will enforce data integrity and provide an index in one go.

Comment: does creating a primary key automatically create an index?

Comment: Making the WorkDate the primary key? Not unique since many users could have the same WorkDate.

Comment: No, you'd make the user id + work date together a primary (composite) key. Yes, a PK always has an index.

Answer (score 1):

You really should index on both the date and the user id. At the minimum, just index the user id.

Comment: you recommend a composite index?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a UserID index for the moment.

If you find the performance better with an additional date index, go ahead and create it.

Nothing prevents you from adding an additional date index in the future if you need to search by date regardless of the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you say each user will have 1 detail for date then it should be a unique index on (userId,  workDate)

Comment: you recommend a composite index?

Comment: yeah, composite unique index (once again, unique if one user can have at most 1 detail for date)